# Difference between two datetime variables in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have two datetime variables as below in my PowerBuilder (2017) code:

var1 = "09/02/2020 23:59:59"
var2 = "09/03/2020 00:00:02"

I need to find out the difference between these two dates in seconds (in this case, 3 seconds) How can I do this?

--Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution.

ll_time1 = secondsafter(time(adt_start), time("23:59:59")) + 1

ll_time2 = secondsafter(time("00:00:00"), time(adt_end))

ll_retval = ll_time1 + ll_time2

Comment: This doesn't really consider that the times are on different days.

Answer (score 0):

Try the SecondsAfter method, eg., ll_dif = SecondsAfter( var1, var2)

Alternatively you could issue a sql statement with the DateDiff method (SQL Server use the DateDiff(second, var1, var2), other DBMS you have to look up).

Comment: SecondsAfter function takes Time variable as parameters, I need to consider the date as well. I am expecting below results:

var1 = "09/02/2020 23:59:59" var2 = "09/03/2020 00:00:02" => Difference: 3 seconds
var1 = "09/02/2020 23:59:59" var2 = "09/03/2020 23:59:59" => Difference: 86400 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference between dates and then the difference between times.

Here is an example from "edit source".

```
global type gf_secondsafter from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function long gf_secondsafter (readonly datetime adt_start, readonly datetime adt_end)
end prototypes

global function long gf_secondsafter (readonly datetime adt_start, readonly datetime adt_end);

constant long lc_hours_in_day = 24, lc_minutes_in_hour = 60, lc_seconds_in_minute = 60

date ld_start, ld_end
time lt_start, lt_end

long ll_days, ll_seconds, ll_result

ld_start = date( adt_start )
lt_start = time( adt_start )

ld_end = date( adt_end )
lt_end = time( adt_end )

ll_days = DaysAfter( ld_start, ld_end )

ll_seconds = SecondsAfter ( lt_start, lt_end )

//This is the number of days multiplied by the number of seconds in a day
ll_result = ll_days * lc_hours_in_day * lc_minutes_in_hour * lc_seconds_in_minute
// Add the seconds from the time difference
ll_result += ll_seconds


return ll_result
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

First; we will create a helper function called relativedatetime_1second() return the relative datetime after 1 second:

```
global type relativedatetime_1second from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function datetime relativedatetime_1second (date dt, time tm)
end prototypes

global function datetime relativedatetime_1second (date dt, time tm);

time new_tm
date new_dt


//   return datetime after 1 second(s)

new_tm = tm
if new_tm = 23:59:59 then
    new_dt = RelativeDate(dt,1)
    new_tm = 00:00:00
elseif new_tm = 00:00:00 then
    new_dt = dt
    new_tm = 00:00:01
else
    new_dt = dt
    new_tm = RelativeTime(tm,1)
end if
return datetime(new_dt, new_tm)
end function
```

Secondly; create a recursive function called diffdatetime() return the diff in seconds between two datetime variables:

```
global type DiffDateTime from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function long diffdatetime (datetime adt_date1, datetime adt_date2)
end prototypes

global function long diffdatetime (datetime adt_date1, datetime adt_date2);

datetime new_dt, next_dt
long seconds,   seconds1, period, remaining_period


//   return diff in seconds between two datetime

//suppose always date1 smaller otherwise return negative

period = DaysAfter ( date(adt_date1), date(adt_date2) ) -1
new_dt = adt_date1
if period = -1 then //same day
    seconds = SecondsAfter ( time(adt_date1), time(adt_date2) )
elseif period = 0 then //one day counts seconds one by one
    do 
        new_dt = relativedatetime_1second(date(adt_date1), time(adt_date1))
        adt_date1 = new_dt 
        seconds =seconds + 1
    loop until adt_date1 = adt_date2
else //extract one day concept plus the remaining days-after
    next_dt = datetime(RelativeDate(date(adt_date1), 1), time(adt_date2))
    seconds1 = diffdatetime(adt_date1, next_dt)


    remaining_period = period  * 24 * 60 * 60 

    seconds = seconds1 + remaining_period
end if
return seconds
end function
```

Finally; getting the difference between datetime1& datetime2 (per seconds) as the following:

```
messagebox("Seconds", string(diffdatetime(var1, var2)))
```

*Notes:  if datetime2 occurs before datetime1, diffdatetime() returns a negative number

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner works just fine for me

There are 86400 seconds in a day so it's just adding
the converted daysafter result with the secondsafter result

If datetime2 is greater than datetime1 the result will be positive

If they are equal, 0

Else, negative

```
RETURN (DaysAfter(Date(datetime1), Date(datetime2)) * 86400) + SecondsAfter(Time(datetime1), Time(datetime2))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long ll_time1, ll_time2

ll_time1 = secondsafter(time(adt_start), time("23:59:59")) + 1

ll_time2 = secondsafter(time("00:00:00"), time(adt_end)) 

return (ll_time1 + ll_time2)
```

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value." Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.